# OptimisticConcurrencyException that is cleared by restarting IIS

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-application-insights

I work on a web application using MVC and Entity Framework 6.1. We typically have around 100 concurrent users load balanced across two IIS servers.

Twice in the last two months we've had periods where numerous users report seeing errors that are caused by OptimisticConcurrencyException ("Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.")

Based on the logs in Application Insights we can see many instances of this exception during the period when users were reporting problems, up to 10 per minute. This affected many users, but only one of the load balanced webservers. A range of update/delete operations where affected.

The first time this occurred we were able to resolve it by restarting IIS on the affected server. We then didn't see a single occurrence of the exception for about 6 weeks, until it suddenly started happening again. Again, restarting IIS was able to resolve it.

Most people seeing this exception appear to see it consistently across environments and can fix it by making a change to their EF models. What I've seen seems to be more a server-related problem. Possibly a cache that is not being cleared when appropriate.

What steps can I take to identify the cause of this issue? Is there additional logging I could configure?

Comment: if this issue does actually not occur consistently, I'd think those are actual concurrency errors, so you should reduce the time between retrieving the data (or attaching it to the context) and saving it back to the database.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro These are web requests. Each request last less than one minute, but the problem continues for hours. If the data is out of date, it is because EF is providing it from a stale cache, not because our application has been hanging on to it for too long.

Comment: the request itself is not the problem, but the context keeping the data in its changetracker. read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx and use one context per request.